# how to count the same value twice in query

Tags: mysql, sql

the result am getting from this query below is obviously one file, this one file has just rur in whataver column, I want to have two entries with the same file, i am interested in having that counted twice.
            filename   size    type(this is an enum)
             ABC    10mb     rur,way

```
        select filename,,size,type, (case when type like '%rur%' then 'rurroad' when type like '%way%' then 'hway' end) as whatever 
        from files as f,metadata as v where f.id = v.id 
        and filename like 'ANC'
        and type like '%rur%'
```

my result is

```
         filename   size    type(this is an enum)       whatever
         ABC    10 mb     rur,way                          rur
```

i want to get

```
         filename   size    type(this is an enum)       whatever
         ABC    10 mb     rur,way                          rur
         ABC    10 mb     rur,way                          way
```

at the same time, my file has size and usually I want to know how many MB do I have with rur, and how many with way. I want to create a pivot table summary thats why I want them all in one view/table. so i want to also get the size of 10mb rur and 10 mb way if possible. otherwise i can avoid counting the size that way

I want to get the result as i have 30% rur 20% way and xx% null

Comment: Your `whatever` column doesn't match what your `case` statement returns.

Comment: it just returns a null

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `UNION`:

```
select filename, size, type, (case when type like '%rur%' then 'rurroad' when type like '%way%' then 'hway' end) as whatever 
    from files as f, metadata as v where f.id = v.id 
    and filename like 'ANC'
    and type like '%rur%'

union all

select filename, size, type, (case when type like '%rur%' then 'rurroad' when type like '%way%' then 'hway' end) as whatever 
    from files as f, metadata as v where f.id = v.id 
    and filename like 'ANC'
    and type like '%way%' -- here we select %way% records - records with "rur,way" will appear in both queries.
```

PS: unless MySQL does not support it. Not sure, but my guess is that it does, it's ANSI SQL after all.
PPS: [it does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).